# Convert array name to string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a bunch of arrays, and a bunch of folders with files I'm trying to get to. The items in the arrays correspond to the file names and the array names match the folder names.

So I have

```
 var myArray = ['my', 'file', 'here'];
 var myArray2 = ['some', 'more', 'files'];
```

& similar as audio files. For example `myArray/my.mp3'

I'm trying to create a string like that dynamically. I wanted to somehow convert my array names to strings but apparently that can't be done. Any other solutions much appreciated.

Comment: You never want variable name strings in your program. Please, tell us what you are [actually trying to do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript dynamic variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/javascript-dynamic-variable-name)

Comment: OK I will edit the question now to be more specific to what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question.
If you want flexibility, you could use an object. Initialize it at the beginning of your life-cycle app like so:

```
var obj = { name: 'tmp', value: null }
```

Later, you could assign both a name and a value to your object based on the user action:

```
obj['name'] = 'chosenArray';
obj['value'] = myArrayTwo;
```

Hope this helps,

R.

Answer (score 0):

You technically CAN access a variable using a string containing its name:

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,4];
var array2 = [5,6,7,8];

var pick = "array2";

var chosen = window[pick];
```

and you can also **create** a global variable that way

```
var newvarname = "array3";

window[newvarname] = [9,10,11,12];
```

This works because `window` in a browser is a predefined object that contains all the variables and the functions. You in addition to change and access globals using `window` you can also iterate over all the global variables:

```
// Collect names of all globally defined arrays
arrays = [];
for (var n in window) {
    if (window[n] && window[n].constructor == Array)
        arrays.push(n);
}
```

but I can think very few cases in which you may want to do that (if you have a function or a variable named "foo" and the directory contains a file named "foo", do you really want to destroy your function/variable?).

Probably you should simply use an object to store your files

```
var myobj = {};
myobj[filename] = ...;
```

Comment: He seems to want the exact opposite, getting the variable name out of the value

Comment: @Bergi: wacky. Added description of how to do such a crime.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use an object where property names are programatically accessible:

```
var audioFiles = {
    "myArray": ['my', 'file', 'here'],
    "myArray2": ['some', 'more', 'files']
};
```

You can easily loop that object, and access the arrays dynamically via [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators).